# R - How to remove special characters + escape sequences from JSON data so I can use JSONLITE on it?

Tags: json, r, twitter, lexical-analysis

Going to just and provide a ton of info below with data, code, etc to finally get this solved.  So first portion will just be an explanation.

**Explanation** - Program to automatically extract Tweets from Twitter. For reasons, I am storing certain values from them I care about (Description, Location, TweetID, etc) into a comma-delimited CSV file.  I use HTTR to "GET" the tweets, the `HTTR::content` function to store them, then convert these to a more workable form using `jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON( ))`.  This works 90% of the time, but sometimes tweets have invisible escape characters embedded in them. Things like `\003`, `GS` as it appears in Notepad++, and other such special characters.  These cause jsonlite to crash.  I'd like to remove them.

So **the code that works for 90%** of the tweets looks like this:

```
mentions = GET(final_url, sig)
json = content(mentions)
json2 = jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(json))
allMentions = json2$statuses
colNames = names( unlist(allMentions[1,], use.names=TRUE ) )
```

Then a bunch more code to actually parse the tweets and pull out things like user_ids, text and latitude.

It **crashes here at json2= line.**  With error:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid character inside string.
  Foundation and 42nd President of the United States. Follow 
              (right here) ------^
```

Or:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid character inside string.
   No Mission Too Difficult, No Sacrifice Too Great, Duty First. DAV, VFW.
                               (right here) ------^
```

So the first set of tweets that produces the first error, there is in notepad++ showing an escape character 003 after of.  In the second, you can see a "GS" character after Great.

So the **attempted fix was to use Gsub.**  Replace special characters.  The problem was, then my data isn't in UTF-8 format anymore for some reason.  So then I convert to UTF-8.

```
json = content(mentions)
json = gsub("[\001-\026]*", "", json, fixed=TRUE)
json = iconv(json, "UTF-8")
json2 = jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(json))
allMentions = json2$statuses
```

Now the jsonlite part works! Perfect, but not really.

**Now I crash at "allMentions = json2$statuses"**

```
    $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Which makes sense, because the output for json2 now is....

```
   [1] "NA"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   [2] "list(completed_in = 0.131, max_id = 660500744261382144, max_id_str =        \"660500744261382146\", next_results = \"?      max_id=660499749334859776&q=%40HillaryClinton%20until%3A2015-11-     01&lang=en&count=100&include_entities=1&result_type=recent\", query = \"%40HillaryClinton+until%3A2015-11-01\", refresh_url = \"?since_id=660500744261382146&q=%40HillaryClinton%20until%3A2015-11-01&lang=en&result_type=recent&include_entities=1\", count = 100, since_id = 658634677922738176, since_id_str = \"658634677922738176\")"
```

This puts me at a loss.  Do I persue fixing the error from this end now, and hunting down this, and risk this screwing up what was working for me previously?  Do I go back to trying to figure out how to get rid of those Escape Characters / Invisible characters some other way?

Any advice on these errors would be met with much appreciation.

Comment: Do you have the status ID for one of the problematic tweets? Might help track down the issue.

Comment: Sure, I can provide that.

Comment: TweetID : 658634677922738176  from Bill Clinton's profile. All of his tweets cause a problem, because escape character 003 exists within his profile description.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this might not be the perfect answer - I'm not experienced with R.

Regarding the bio of `@pinoybreed808`:

`No Mission Too Difficult, No Sacrifice Too Great, Duty First. DAV, VFW.`

The unusual character appears after `Duty First` and before `.` it's actually [U+001D](http://graphemica.com/001D) - I've no idea *why* they're using it, but there are a couple of strategies for coping with unusual characters like this.

Firstly, you can simply `gsub` them out - although I'm not sure of `R` syntax, it doesn't look like you're capturing the character correctly.

Secondly, you could try URL Encoding the data before storing it.  That would turn the character into `%1D`.

Thirdly, I don't see why this character is causing issues for JSONlite.  It may be worth raising a bug in either R or JSONlite about how it copes with weird characters.

Comment: Hello sir.  Thanks for the input.  I did try gsub as a method.  While my current "test" doesn't account for the character U+001D from that tweet, I am testing on a small subset with the other example from Bill Clinton's profile where he has escape character \003.  Once I do the gsub in that case, jsonlite works beautifully.  The problem is the result now works with the rest of my code.  I go to do json2$statuses, and get atomic vector error.